# Trouble configuring Netplan w/ multiple VLANS and Bridges on Single NIC for KVM/QEMU

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, netplan, vlan

The simplicity of Netplan has me stumped again.

Attempting to configure a single NIC with multiple subnets to be used with kvm/qemu VM hosting.

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 
Switch: TP-Link TL-SG108E
```

I have (1) bridge 192.168.1.22 without a VLAN I can access the bridge IP and the IP of the VM associated with that bridge 192.168.1.23

I am attempting to setup (2) VLANs 192.168.3.2 & 192.168.4.2 for VMs 192.168.3.3 & 192.168.4.3

I am using 802.1Q VLAN on the TL-SG108E

```
ID  NAME     Mem   Tag   UnTag
1   Default        1-8   1-8
11  vm1      1,3    1     3
12  vm2      1,3    1     3
```

Followed various Netplan examples without success.

Tempted to add a second NIC with two ports and move on but hesitate to do so as this task should be simple to accomplish.

Comment: Ubuntu 22 is a version number for Ubuntu Core 22 is that what you are using? If so say Core if not please edit with the actual version info.

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS